# Add hostname in front of export

Tags: powershell

I am writing PS1 script to export all certificates stored on AD computers and I don't know how to add before every certificate listed with get-childitem I have create following code :

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
# Vnos Lokacije 
[string]$lokacija = Read-Host "Vnesi Lokacijo KK ..."

# Današnji Datum
$datum = Get-Date

$lokacija = $lokacija.ToUpper()

# Od danes do 10 dni starih računalnikov / aktivnih 10 dni
$danes = $datum.AddDays(-10)

$podatek = Get-ADComputer -SearchBase "OU=$lokacija,DC=dc,DC=dc,DC=com" -Properties * -Filter {LastLogonDate -gt $danes} | Select Name
Foreach ($podatk in $podatek) {
    Get-Childitem cert:LocalMachine\Root -Recurse
    where-object { $_.Subject -like "*$hostname*" } 
    }


# Export-Csv -Path "C:\Users\user\Desktop\Test.csv"
```

So in this export I'd like to have in front of every exported certificate a domain computer hostname that I can "manipulate" with excel for further readings.

Please help... ASSAP :)

Comment: $hostname = $env:computername   this what you are looking for?

Comment: Also if you're going to run this on all your client computer, they would all need to have the AD Powershell tools installed (remote management tools) if remote-powershell is enabled on the client computers you could also change the script to remotely execute the commands on the client computers